Openapi 3 code generator kotlin-spring enum type mapping
I would like to reuse my own enum class when generating code from my OpenApi 3 specification.
When I run the default OpenApi 3 code generation with the kotlin-spring template it will create a new enum class for each object in the schema, but I would like to use my own enum class. Because now I get multiple enum class all over the place, which are actually the same.
This is my OpenApi 3 spec file:
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Export API
  description: Export API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:

  /exports:
    post:
      tags:
        - v1
      operationId: createExport
      parameters:
        - name: export-type
          required: true
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
            format: exportType
            enum:
              - EXCEL
              - CSV
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/ExportRequest"
        required: true
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "OK"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ExportResponse"

components:
  schemas:
    ExportRequest:
      type: object
      required:
        - exportType
      properties:
        exportType:
          type: string
          format: exportType
          enum:
            - EXCEL
            - CSV
    ExportResponse:
      type: object
      required:
        - exportType
      properties:
        exportType:
          type: string
          format: exportType
          enum:
            - EXCEL
            - CSV

Maven configuration:
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <importMappings>
                                <importMapping>ExportType=labs.ExportType</importMapping>
                            </importMappings>
                            <typeMappings>
                                <typeMapping>string+exportType=ExportType</typeMapping>
                            </typeMappings>
                            <configOptions>
                                <enumPropertyNaming>UPPERCASE</enumPropertyNaming>
                            </configOptions>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static/export.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>kotlin-spring</generatorName>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <apiPackage>labs.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>labs.model</modelPackage>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>./</sourceFolder>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <reactive>false</reactive>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <annotationLibrary>none</annotationLibrary>
                                <documentationProvider>none</documentationProvider>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

My custom enum class:
package labs

enum class ExportType {
    CSV,
    EXCEL,
}

Generated API code which is fine and with my custom enum class
@Validated
@RequestMapping("\${api.base-path:}")
interface ExportsApi {
    @RequestMapping(
            method = [RequestMethod.POST],
            value = ["/exports"],
            produces = ["application/json"],
            consumes = ["application/json"]
    )
    fun createExport(@NotNull  @Valid @RequestParam(value = "export-type", required = true) exportType: labs.ExportType, @Valid @RequestBody exportRequest: ExportRequest): ResponseEntity<ExportResponse> {
        return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
    }
}

Generated request class without my custom enum class
data class ExportRequest(

    @field:Valid
    @get:JsonProperty("exportType", required = true) val exportType: ExportRequest.ExportType
) {
    enum class ExportType(val value: labs.ExportType) {

        @JsonProperty("EXCEL") EXCEL("EXCEL"),
        @JsonProperty("CSV") CSV("CSV")
    }
}

Generated response class without my custom enum class
data class ExportResponse(

    @field:Valid
    @get:JsonProperty("exportType", required = true) val exportType: ExportResponse.ExportType
) {
    enum class ExportType(val value: labs.ExportType) {

        @JsonProperty("EXCEL") EXCEL("EXCEL"),
        @JsonProperty("CSV") CSV("CSV")
    }
}

I would like to have the following for the request and response classes:
data class ExportResponse(

    @field:Valid
    @get:JsonProperty("exportType", required = true) val exportType: labs.ExportType
)

